# MSVCP120.dll was not found

Tags: c++, package, redistributable

I have Windows Vista 64-bit installed in VirtualBox. When I try to run my C++ program developed in Visual Studio 2013, I get error "This application has failed to start because MSVCP120.dll was not found". I installed C++ redistributable packages for Visual Studio 2013 (both x86 and x64) but still getting the same error. I do have file "msvcp120.dll" in both Windows\System32 and Windows\SysWOW64. How to fix this?

Comment: Please check your executable with dependency checker on machine on which it is  not running. That will show you the missing files.

Comment: As CreativeMind said, you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to analyze the DLLs your program links against.

Comment: You're sure the build machine built with the same service pack level as the redist you installed? The redist for a SP cut of the runtime lib runs as a SxS (side-by-side). Last I checked, anyway. Been awhile. In other words, did you install the redist package taken directly from the redist folder of the build machine that created your executable?